# Problem executing file & unable to open terminal window

Tags: command-line, executable

i have latest Ubuntu - and using it as a LIve CD
1. i have an executable file (file manager confirms that file is executable) that won't execute & File manager won't let me tick the permission box that confirms file is executable
2.how do i run the command line i.e. can't seem to be able to open a terminal window ?? i thought i might be able to chmod the file (i.e. u+x ) or even give myself administrators rights - what is root's password with the Live CD - i let boot-up procedures log in for me 
Hope someone can help me 
regards
Judy Adams

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to boot ubuntu from the CD?  This is actually a boot process rather than a run process.  You may need to tell your BIOS that it should boot from your CD before the harddrive, but other than that the system should run smoothly, assuming that you created the CD (or USB) according to [the normal instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I don't believe that there is a password for root access on the live CD, and to open a terminal from within Ubuntu press alt+ctl+t